# Linear to exponential ramp converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, converter

Hi, I need a circuit to convert a linear ramp to an exponential curve, as shown below.

Can anyone help?

[image]

These are simple voltage ramps, not periodic waves.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if English is your first language or not, but to say "I need you to .." is not going to help your cause. At. All.

Comment: sorry, how can I put it in the right way?

Comment: "I need a circuit to convert a linear ramp to an exponential curve, as shown below. Can anyone help?" In English, "I need you to..." is usually used by a boss to a subordinate. With that out of the way, how steep a slope do you need at the beginning of the exponential, and what time span do you need? Please explain what you need, and why you need it, in as much detail as you can. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Corrected. "How steep" is not critical, voltage range is 0-5V and the time span varies from 0 to 10 seconds. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The upper and lower graphs show two different transfer functions. Do you want a separate circuit for each, or a single circuit that handles the 'downward' and 'upward' slopes differently?

Comment: Since my ramp gen has only one output, and it can be upwards or downwards, a single converter is needed.

Answer (score 2):

In hardware, one way is like this:

[image]